# How to create or update an entity in a single mutation

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo-server, graphql-js, typegraphql

Is there an accepted pattern to create or update an item in a single`createOrUpdate` mutation where the fields for creating and updating vary?
For example here is the type and the mutation i'm trying to create:

```
// The item shape
{
  id: string
  name: string
}

// the mutation pseudocode 
mutation {
  saveItem(input: ItemCreate | ItemUpdate ){
    if(input.id){
      // update
    }
        
    if(!input.id){
      // create 
    }
  }
}
```

It seems like these are the options being used:

1. Use nullable types and then run a type check to find whether to update or create

```
input UpdateOrCreate {
    id: string // nullable
    title: string // nullable
}
```

You would then have a typeguard for the different scenarios to check whether to update or create the item and that the correct combination of properties exist. The interface for the client is way nicer but it means you have write typeguards and convert the input type to a more specific type

2. Split the different input types into properties

```
input UpdateOrCreate {
  updateItems: [ItemUpdateInput]
  createItems: [ItemCreateInput]
}
```

This seems like the graphql way as the input is validated however the interface is very poor for the client because we are telling them that they have to keep track of updates and creates

Is there a standard approach to this?

Comment: You have to create a mutation similar to an [`upsert`](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/upsert) method. However, the input type becomes very complicated and hard to maintain since you must use `class-validator`'s `@ValidateIf` and check for combinations of properties (e.g., validate if the `id` property is given). It's far easier and more maintainable to split into two mutations: one for creating items and the other for updating them (better to update a single item at a time).

Answer (score 0):

I would propose that neither of these is The GraphQL Way™... at least not yet. There is [currently a proposal](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-wg/blob/main/rfcs/InputUnion.md) to support input unions, which I think matches the pattern you're looking for. That feature is not currently accepted, but could be soon. We're all watching to see how those proposals pan out.

Before I go further, I have to add a caveat that there's not really "a standard approach". This is a pattern I've used for several years and is reflected by the opinions of some others, but everyone has their own flavor.

---

My "hot take":

> Be explicit first so that a third party wouldn't have to "guess your meaning", "know your implementation details" or read your documentation to know what to do.

On one hand, the concept of an "upsert" or a "CreateOrUpdate" is relatively common in both REST and ORMs, with the expectation that if you're passing an `id`, it's an update and if not, it's a create, so I could absolutely see you going that direction. On the other hand, the following thoughts:

1. Do you have to send THE ENTIRE object on each call to an update? Should you have to?
2. If not, are some fields actually optional, but only in the case of an update? If so, you're getting into the territory of [Anemic Mutations](https://xuorig.medium.com/graphql-mutation-design-anemic-mutations-dd107ba70496). What fields are *actually* optional vs "only optional if..."?
3. If every field is required all the time, what does it mean to send an `id` or not? Is it actually *create* vs *update*, or does your system allow a pre-generated IDs to be provided? If you're using an auto-increment the answer is most likely "no". If you're using UUIDs, the answer *could be "yes"*. If I pre-generate an ID and send it, should I get a NotFound error back because it's an update, or should it create because it's an upsert?

The most common approach I've seen (and used) is to split this into two separate mutations, which makes things a bit more explicit. In an `update` mutation, an `id` field would absolutely be required. In a `create` mutation, if you allowed pre-generated IDs, that's easily determined by having a nullable `id`, and this is where I'd expect an error if it exists.

---

That being said, I've also seen things like what you've got in the second option, but used when dealing with some batch action.

```
input UpdateOrCreateLineItems {
  orderId: ID!
  lineItemsToCreate: [LineItemCreateInput!]
  lineItemsToUpdate: [LineItemUpdateInput!]
  lineItemsToDelete: [ID!]
}
```

Caveat again: this is my take based on my needs and your opinions and needs aren't the same as mine.